# how to install boost/asio.hpp library for C++ visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries

Hello I am trying to install this library for use in one of my visual studio projects.

I know I have to go to \project properties-linker-general-additional library Directories but once I get there I don't know what to do.

I am stuck here :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step-by-step tutorial for installing, (optionally) building, and referencing boost in Windows: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#get-boost

Answer (score 0):

1. Obtain a copy of boost and put it to a folder `boost_root` (name as you please). If you haven't done it already, [the easiest way is to get a precompiled zip from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)
2. Find the directory where your boost binaries are located. It usually is under the `lib` subdirectory, ie `boost_root\libs`.
3. Under the *Additional library directory* of visual studio (the one you mention in your post), enter the full or relative path to the boost dll directory, ie `path_to_boost_root\boost_root\libs`